# convert image.jpg to Base64 string

Tags: android

error log is image:null

my problem is not proper convert image to base64.

my code encode image

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivProfilePic.getDrawable();   
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap(); 
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bos); byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bb,Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("ImageBase34", encodedString);
```

decode string to covert image

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(userDetailBean.getProfile_picture().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Log.d("img", String.valueOf(base64Bitmap));
ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(base64Bitmap);
```

---

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: i have check response decode image base64   
my log cat print Messge Log.d:img null display

Comment: @PiyushAmipara have you solved this issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **encodedString** as the first parameter in the Base64.decode() method instead of **userDetailBean.getProfile_picture()**.

You need to change your code like this.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_default_user);
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bos); byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bb,Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("ImageBase34", encodedString);
```

decode string to covert image

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Log.d("img", String.valueOf(base64Bitmap));
imageView.setImageBitmap(base64Bitmap);
```